# How you do you call a method once rendering is done in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, quill

I have am building a Vue app that includes a QuillJS editor in a tab. I have a simple `setTab(tabName)` Vue method that shows/hides tabs with the `v-if` directive.

```js
methods: {
  setTab: function (tabName) {
    this.view = tabName;
    if(tabName === 'compose') {
      var editor = new Quill('#editor', {
        modules: { toolbar: '#toolbar' },
        theme: 'snow'
      });
    }
  }
}
```

My tab is basically like this:

```html
<div id="composer" v-if="tabName === 'compose'">
  <!-- toolbar container -->
  <div id="toolbar">
    <button class="ql-bold">Bold</button>
    <button class="ql-italic">Italic</button>
  </div>
  <!-- editor container -->
  <div id="editor">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently, I'm getting an error because the `#editor` element does not yet exist when I am calling `new Quill(...)`. How do I delay that QuillJS initialization on the page so that it doesn't happen until after the `#editor` is already there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`this.$nextTick()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick) to defer a callback to be executed after the next DOM update cycle (e.g., after changing a data property that causes a render-update).

For example, you could do this:

```js
methods: {
  setTab: function (tabName) {
    this.view = tabName;
    if(tabName === 'compose') {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        var editor = new Quill('#editor', {
          modules: { toolbar: '#toolbar' },
          theme: 'snow'
        });
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) hook.

```
mounted: function () {
  // Code that will run only after the
  // entire view has been rendered
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A clean way to do this is not to rely on selectors but make Quill editor a self-contained component:

```
<template>
    <div class="quill-editor">
      <!-- toolbar container -->
      <div ref="toolbar">
        <button class="ql-bold">Bold</button>
        <button class="ql-italic">Italic</button>
      </div>
      <!-- editor container -->
      <div ref="editor">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  ...
  name: "QuillEditor",
  mounted() {
    this.quill = new Quill(this.$refs.editor, {
      modules: { toolbar: this.$refs.toolbar },
      theme: 'snow'
    });
  }
  ...
</script>
```